# Excel proper date format in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have worksheet named as `Correlation_Process` and it contains the field of `Birthdate` and `Age`.

what i want to do is to get the age based on the birthdate i already get the age based on the birthdate using excel formula. but some of the rows returns some error like this #VALUE!

Here's my excel formula to get the age: =DATEDIF(A:A,NOW(),"y")
and Here's my date format (Month/day/year) i dont get the error shown in picture which is `#VALUE!` when some of the rows are showing the expected output
anyone can help?

```
=DATEDIF(A:A,NOW(),"y")
```

[image]

Comment: Try `=ISTEXT(A3)`  where A3 is the cell of the date where you are getting the errors.  you may have mixed text date value with formatted excel serial dates

Comment: I would be curious on what data format is being used, as the error only seems to occur where the middle figure is greater than 12.

Comment: As Tim Biegeleisen pointed out, you should use `=DATEDIF(A2,NOW(),"y")` and that should work if the format of the dates are correct.  Otherwise, use `=DATEDIF(VALUE(A2),NOW(),"y")` should convert the format and calculate the age for you too.

Answer (score 0):

The formula entered into cell `B2` should be this:

```
=DATEDIF(A2, NOW(), "y")
```

Copy this formula down the `B` column and you should have the data you want.

The general formula for `DATEDIF` is

```
DATEDIF(first_date, second_date, UNIT)
```

Comment: This code works but still showing some #VALUES! i dont know what is the problem. If it is in my excel or just in my code? just a thought

Comment: Please inspect the date values that are in error.  Is there any rogue whitespace there?  Are those A cells in error of the date type?

Comment: i checked manually all of the rows if there's whitespaces and there's no whitespaces from the given data and i also checked the date type of the data in CTRL+1 and i chose the format of date like in the given data shown in picture

Comment: Hmm...did you also check the formulas of the individual cells which are in error?  Errors always happen for a reason; let's try to find out why.

Comment: I checked it again and we saw that our format is mm/dd/yy, and the function of the current date NOW() is in dd/mm/yy. How to convert the format of NOW() into format that will be same as mm/dd/yy so we can formulate a formula to get the age

Comment: That can't be the explanation because telling from your screen capture the formula seems to be working with only a few exceptions.  The format you _see_ doesn't say anything about how Excel internally stores a date.  So long as column `A` is a date column, this should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try something like this:

```
=TEXT(TODAY();"yyyy")-TEXT(A2;"yyyy")
```

And see if it works

Answer (score 0):

OK lets go back to basics and the sure fired way to snag the date.  We will rip apart the date manually and then recombine it.

Start by ripping apart the date into Day, Month and Year

```
Day
=MID(A2,4,2)
Month
=Left(A2,2)
Year
=Right(A2,4)
```

Now we will want to combine those values into the DATE(year,month,day) function.

```
=DATE(Right(A2,4),Left(A2,2),MID(A2,4,2))
```

Now you will want to use that in your DATEDIF formula

```
=DATEDIF(DATE(Right(A2,4),Left(A2,2),MID(A2,4,2)),NOW(),"y")
```

This assumes your dates are in the A column starting in ROW 2.  Place the above formula in B2 and copy down.  This is all based on your dates being text and not serial dates.